# Installing windows service

Tags: windows-services, installation

I have a windows service (.exe) file. How to install it as a service from the windows command prompt in a deployment system?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See:

> Using SC to deploy Windows services
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810435.aspx

The "SC" (Service Controller) utility should be on any Windows system, really.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [InstallUtil](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/50614e95(VS.80).aspx) :)

Comment: Should we have to download it seperately? The deployment environment wont have any sdk's available..

Comment: No, I just include it in the release of the service; it can be run as-is.